# Simple Array Sorting

Tags: php, mysqli

I've read a million complicated questions on sorting arrays.  I have something super simple, but I'm just not able to wrap my head around it.

I have a table in my db that has scores for games.  The column labels are team1_score and team_2 score.  I realize that if all the scores were in one column, I could sort them with my SQL query, but they're not.

I need to know how to fetch the results from those columns, and sort them highest to lowest and ideally assign those to variables such as $first_place and $second_place

I'm sorry I'm  a noob and I've done a lot of research before coming on here, so please be gentle.

So, I have something like this...
 My program keeps track of scores at a kids camp and there are multiple camps. Each row has id, camp_name, camp_logo and then goes into team1_name, team1_logo, team1_score and so on through 10 teams. Ideally, I'd like to have the query fetch all those scores, and output them in Descending order with something like First Place: xxx points (team name) (team logo)

I can sort the scores with this...

```
  $query = "SELECT team1_score, team2_score FROM camps ";
  $scores = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
  $scores_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($scores);
  arsort($scores_array);
  foreach ($scores_array as $key => $value) {
  echo "score - [" . $key . "] = " . $value . "\n";
  }
```

but I don't know how to associate the name and logo with those keys. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It seems likely that with a creative `ORDER BY` condition (which can be any expression, not just a column name) you may be able to do it in the SQL. Can you post a sample of unsorted rows from your table, together with a sample of what the same rows would look like after your sort operation?  We'll need that sample to attempt either SQL ordering or something in the PHP code.

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me!  My program keeps track of scores at a kids camp and there are multiple camps. Each row has id, camp_name, camp_logo and then goes into team1_name, team1_logo, team1_score and so on through 10 teams.  

Ideally, I'd like to have the query fetch all those scores, and output them in Descending order with something like First Place: xxx points (team name) (team logo)

Comment: I can sort the scores with this       $query = "SELECT team1_score, team2_score FROM camps ";
      $scores = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
      $scores_array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($scores);
      arsort($scores_array);
      foreach ($scores_array as $key => $value) {
      echo "score - [" . $key . "] = " . $value . "\n";
      } 
but I don't know how to associate the name and logo with those keys. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Can you repost this stuff using the `edit` link below your post rather than in the comment thread? It will gain appropriate syntax highlighting and formatting. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This *can* actually done by SQL. You could use [`greatest`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) and [`least`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) to get the top and bottom scores, respectively, and then also sort by them:

```
SELECT   GREATEST(team1_score, team2_score), 
         LEAST(team1_score, team2_score)
FROM     camps 
ORDER BY 1 DESC, 2 DESC
```

Comment: Ahhh. I didn't know that.  That's great to know. I probably should have explained that my actual system will grow to 10 teams, so greatest/least won't really work there, right?  Thank you so much for the feedback.